# What examples of existence forcing proofs are there?

Tags: set-theory, lo.logic, soft-question, forcing

Forcing proofs tend to be fairly constructive, in the sense that if I claim that there is a forcing that does something, I usually prove this by constructing that forcing.

There are only a handful of exceptions, where we prove that a forcing notion that does the trick exists, but we use abstract argument instead of specifying the forcing. For example Itay Neeman's proof of the consistency of the tree property up to $\aleph_{\omega+1}$,

> *Neeman, Itay*, [**The tree property up to $\aleph_{\omega+1}$**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1017/jsl.2013.25), J. Symb. Log. 79, No. 2, 429-459 (2014). [ZBL1338.03099](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1338.03099).

There he proves that there is some $\mu$ which we can collapse (along with additional forcing) to obtain the result. This $\mu$ is not quite specified, we can just show that there are many candidates for it (which themselves may depend on the choice of generics) and we are not picky as to which one to use. (One can argue that even in that case the forcing is *somewhat* specified.)

But I want more. I am looking for proofs that essentially utilize generic absoluteness "in a backwards way". For example:

*Assume that there is no forcing that forces $\varphi$, therefore $\lnot\varphi$ is generically (upwards) absolute. By some external argumentation this is impossible. Therefore there is a forcing which forces $\varphi$.*

> Are there examples of proofs that kind of look like this? Are there other flavors of existence forcing proofs?

Comment: How about "non-explicit" instead of "non-constructive"?

Comment: Andrej, I know that constructive has a specific meaning, but in order to prove that CH is false, I literally construct a forcing that does that. In order to prove that it is consistent from a measurable cardinal that there is a cardinal preserving forcing that changes its cofinality to $\omega$, I literally construct it. I'll be happy to amend my terminology, but the word "explicit" doesn't fit in my head to the situation.

Comment: Well, it was just a suggestion. More generally, we need terminology which distinguishes between "explicit" and "non-explicit" existence/construction. I like "explicit vs. abstract" existence/construction. The word "constructive" has the wrong connotations attached.

Comment: Not to mention that in some sense, this *is* non-constructive in its proper use, we prove that a forcing notion exists, and we just don't quite say anything about which one it is.

Comment: I agree with you, except that the word "constructive" has acquired a different meaning (namely, that a proof is carried out in intuitionistic logic, possibly with some extra anti-classical principles).

Comment: Andrej, I've made yet another change in the terminology (since I forgot to $\rm\TeX$ the title of the paper I cited), I hope that now everyone is happy, and we can move on to find such proof.

Comment: I certainly hope nobody has stopped thinking about your question because we quibbled about a word! (By the way, I find the question very interesting, as I've been collecting such examples.)

Comment: @AndrejBauer Many mathematicians don't agree that the word "constructive" is owned by the intuitionistic logicians. This word is very commonly used in mathematics with a much looser meaning to mean something like "following a construction", even when that construction does not obey the rules of whatever constructive logic one might have in mind. In this sense, I find it over-reaching to claim that the word "constructive" has acquired another meaning in any absolute sense---it has only acquired that meaning in the contexts specifically about constructive logic, and not in mathematics generally.

Comment: I frequently use the word "constructive" to mean just its ordinary mathematical meaning, even when talking about proving something in ZFC using classical logic. For example, one proof of existence is more constructive than another, when the object claimed to exist is exhibited in a more direct way.  This concept is an important mathematical idea, which is correctly captured by the "constructive" terminology, unencumbered by issues of non-classical logic. Indeed, I would say that it is this kind of idea that the intutionistic logic use of "constructive" is harnessing in the first place.

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins: I agree that the word is not "owned" by anybody, but I tihnk it would be good to have some clarity here. Using the word "constructive" in several senses is counter-productive, especially since it diminishes ordinary mathematician's understanding of what each sense of "constructive" means. The notion of "constructive" in the sense of constructive mathematics is precise (derivale in such-and-such formal system). Is the other notion also formal? Are they facets of the same phenomenon? (By the way, I think the answer is positive.)

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins: do you know of formalizations, or at least precise mathematical treatment, of what the common mathematical meaning of "constructive" is supposed to be?

Comment: First thing that comes to mind is showing that the set of forcings fulfilling your goal is  comeager in an appropriate Baire space of posets...

Comment: @AndrejBauer I don't know of any formal accounts of what I have called the common usage of "constructive"; it seems to be used mainly informally. Of course, the informal usage is connected with the usage in constructive logic, which I view as a more extreme form of it. But I also think that the ordinary use of "constructive" is widely understood correctly by mathematicians, and this use should not be discouraged. Rather, it is a very useful concept that is captured by the common use of the word.

Comment: I hope I never discouraged the usage of the wide-spread concept. I think I explained myself clearly enough, I am *discussing* and *asking* about choice of words. You are making it a discussion about who is entitled to use what word, and I think that's a bit counter-productive.

Comment: I don't think Andrej was out of line with his remark. I think that there are plenty of set theoretic concepts which have a particular meaning and some people would argue that they also have a different "broader" "informal use". I think this whole thing went a bit out of hand, so let's instead stop this discussion and focus on finding examples of this kind of proofs!

Comment: Bishop's book Constructive analysis insists on using classical reasoning but changes the definition of the basic objects (real numbers, continuity...).

Comment: In [this paper](https://ivv5hpp.uni-muenster.de/u/rds/MM_implies_star.pdf) showing that $\mathsf{MM}^{++}\implies (\ast)$, the specification of the forcing notion $\mathbb{P}_\lambda$ (pg. eq 8)  and proof that it's non-empty (Lemma 3.2) kind of have this flavor.

Comment: @NotMike: Hmm. I was going to bring this up over beer with David later this evening. Let's see what he has to say to defend himself.

Comment: Make sure to tell him It's a cute use of $\mathcal{L}$-forcing

Comment: I am trying to decide whether the comment thread above has been a constructive discussion or not :)

Comment: @Burak: It was not.

Comment: @AsafKaragila You probably know that Itay’s style of argument has been used by several people subsequently, including Dima, Yair, Mohammad, and myself (with Yair). Probably others.

Comment: @Monroe: Yes, I know.

Comment: @AsafKaragila I may say that Neeman's idea is already used by shelah in his paper "On successors of singular cardinals".  You may look at the proof of "29. Conclusion".

Comment: @AsafKaragila Another note: In the case of tree property, the idea was first used by sinapova in her paper "The tree property at $ℵ_{ω+1}$. J. Symbolic Logic 77 (2012), no. 1, 279–-290.

Comment: (Not sure if this fits the question...) In [arXiv:1511.02687](https://arxiv.org/abs/1511.02687), Brooke-Taylor, Fischer, Friedman, Montoya construct a model with a small basis for an ultrafilter on $\kappa$. Let $\kappa<\kappa^*<\Gamma$ (plus some cardinal arithmetic). If I understood this correctly, they start with an iteration of length $\Gamma^+$, then find a magic (not sure if constructive) set $S \subseteq \Gamma^+$ of "nice" coordinates, which has order type $\kappa^*$, and cut off the iteration at $\sup S$, to get a model where $\mathfrak u=\kappa^*<\Gamma=2^\kappa$.